# How can I remap the keyboard with Perl on Win32?

Tags: perl, winapi, keyboard

I want to remap the keyboard with Perl on Win32 system. Is there any option to do that? If yes, could you provide an example?

Remapping the keyboard means form example when the user presses <kbd>a</kbd>, he gets <kbd>b</kbd> or something else according to the remapping).

Answer (score 5):

[This code](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=503197) claims to address this issue.